# Saving an explicit entity through Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I'm reading data from an Excel file and I need to save this using EF. After reading excel, I construct an entity of type in my EF model - say Holiday.

Chance is that this particular holiday already exist in my DB or may not. I can't know it just by reading the Excel file. So, I check whether that entity exist, if so I have to modify the existing entity or add a new entity.

Following is how I'm handling the logic.

```
 foreach (var holiday in clientDataObj.Holidays)
 {
     // to check for existing holidays, no need to consider the location, as all holidays will anyway exist at root level.
     Holiday existingHoliday =
                ClientContext.Holidays.SingleOrDefault(h => string.Equals(h.Date, holiday.Date));

     if (existingHoliday == null)
     {
         rootLocation.Holidays.Add(holiday);
     }
     else
     {
         holiday.HolidayId = existingHoliday.HolidayId;
         ClientContext.Entry(existingHoliday).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
         ClientContext.Entry(holiday).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
     }
}

ClientContext.SaveChanges();
```

I haven't yet run the code to see if it's working. Can someone give an idea of whether this is the way to do it, or is there any other best practice in addressing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work. Detaching an entity doesn't remove it, it just detaches from the context's tracking.

You need to remove it and add the new one:

```
ClientContext.Entry(existingHoliday).State = EntityState.Deleted;
ClientContext.Entry(holiday).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Also, in the event that there are two same holidays in the excel file, you may pass through one that you already added, so you need to check for that. Detaching here will work because you haven't called `SaveChanges` yet so the entity is not in the database yet:

```
if(ClientContext.Entry(existingHoliday).State == EntityState.Added)
   ClientContext.Entry(existingHoliday).State == EntityState.Detached;
```

I'm not sure about why you are adding them to `rootLocation` when they don't exist on the database, you should be adding them to the context if I follow your logic, so you may have this loop:

```
foreach (var holiday in clientDataObj.Holidays)
{
   Holiday existingHoliday =
                ClientContext.Holidays.SingleOrDefault(h => string.Equals(h.Date, holiday.Date));  
   if (existingHoliday != null)
   {
      holiday.Id = existingHoliday.Id;
      ClientContext.Entry(existingHoliday).State = 
                    ClientContext.Entry(existingHoliday).State == EntityState.Added       
                             ? EntityState.Detached 
                             : EntityState.Deleted;
   }       
   ClientContext.Entry(holiday).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
}
```

Again, I'm not sure what `rootLocation` is so your logic might be different.

As a further optimization, if the holiday list is not too big, you should load it all on memory, instead of calling `SingleOrDefault` on every iteration, which will hit the database.

So have just a single hit to the database loading all of them (again, if there are not too many and memory is not a concern), and search in the client:

```
var allHolidays = ClientContext.Holidays.ToList();    
foreach (var holiday in clientDataObj.Holidays)
{
   Holiday existingHoliday =
                allHolidays.SingleOrDefault(h => string.Equals(h.Date, holiday.Date));
   /* ... */
}
```

This should only hit the database once for querying

Note that if using both this method and the above, you'll need to add the new holidays to the list too, so that they get checked against, if the excel import may have duplicates. This is all unspecced in your question so check the specs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks, you have some valuable suggestions there.

Comment: Hi, I resolved the problem with your suggestion, but there's a new problem now. Appreciate if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202341/ef-associated-entity-is-trying-to-add-to-the-database-when-adding-an-entity