# EF - associated entity is trying to add to the database when adding an entity

Tags: entity-framework

This question is related to:
[Saving an explicit entity through Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37064085/saving-an-explicit-entity-through-entity-framework/37064467#37064467)

Basically, Jcl's approached worked me. But there's another issue when trying to save the changes, because it tries to insert a duplicate entity which I have set as a foriegn key.

I'm reading location objects from an Excel file, and construct location objects. I need to set the TimeZone property of the location. There's a timezone table, and the timezoneid is set as the foreign key in the location table.

```
 TimeZone tz = LocationsRepo.GetTimeZoneByName(timezone);

 if (tz != null)
 {
      currentLocation.TimeZone = tz;
 }
```

Now when I try to save the location as follows:

```
  // Check if an entirely new entity is added or an existing entity is being updated.
            Location existingLocation = locations.SingleOrDefault(
                    l =>
                        l.LocationCode.Equals(location.LocationCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (existingLocation != null)
            {
                location.LocationId = existingLocation.LocationId;
                ClientContext.Entry(existingLocation).State =
                              ClientContext.Entry(existingLocation).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added
                                       ? System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached
                                       : System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            }
   ClientContext.Entry(location).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;


        return ClientContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get the error that I'm trying to insert a duplicate key in the timezone table.  I understand this is because the ClientContext doesn't recognize the location.Timezone because it was set outside the ClientContext. So I tried attaching it:

```
ClientContext.TimeZones.Attach(location.TimeZone);
ClientContext.SaveChanges();
```

Then I get the error that I'm trying to insert a duplication location object. Because this timezone is already set to a location existing in the database, and it's trying to attach that.

What's the workaround for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, and I don't have much time, so I'm not answering for now (just commenting), but you can try to set the `location.Timezone` state as `Modified` right after attaching it (`ClientContext.Entry(location).State = EntityState.Modified`), or you can just query the right object from the database in that context: `location.TimeZone = ClientContext.TimeZones.First(x => x.Id == location.TimeZone.Id)`

Comment: I tried that already. Still the same.